# Truffle Testing, Javascript & Solidity Testing Use Case

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test

I’ve been studying the truffle documentation and saw how little differences were detected between the way solidity testing and javascript testing works. This confuses me as a developer, the documentation offers little information about each testing ways pro's and con's and that really made it hard for me to understand its use case.

- https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-javascript.html
- https://trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/testing/writing-tests-in-solidity.html

I'm gonna be teaching about this concept to developers at my company soon and just want more clarifications on this topic to be sure.

In my opinion , we should choose each testing way by these factors

- Use Case - Javascript testing way

  - Basic smart contract functionality & logic
  - More control since it uses mocha and mocha has a lot of configuration ready on their documentation
- Use Case - Solidity testing way

  - Testing smart contract exceptions
  - Testing smart contract ether transactions

Is this correct? what are your thoughts because i have no idea , hoping someone clears this concept up for me.

Comment: Another division is that with javascript you can test public and external functions (the semantic side) and with solidity you can test internal functions (the implementations details). But there's some overlap, you can call public functions from a solidity tests (but you can't change 'from' easily).